# WPF C# NullReferenceException when navigating

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple problem. I hit a service and if there is no internet available I want to navigate to offline page. The code I'm using to navigate is working for the other pages. But for this page I have the following code and it is giving an error i.e.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
        InitializeComponent();
            WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:45207/MyAPIWebService.svc/getUser");
            try            
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch 
            {
                offlineModePage OFMPage = new offlineModePage();
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(OFMPage);
            }
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: thanks dear but I have already done debugging. I'm unable to find the bug. I want some help here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not set request
try this:

```
WebRequest request=WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:45207/MyAPIWebService.svc/getUser";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

You should also catch a specific Exception.

Comment: I don't have problem in requesting the service. I'm having problem with the navigation. while debugging it shows NavigationService is null.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I Found the problem. I was not closing the parent windows.

Two steps and I got it working.

step 1:

```
(this.Parent as Page).Close();
```

step 2:

Navigate to new page

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("offlineModePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Hope this will help someone :)